# awk print hostname

Tags: awk

How can we specify the hostname of the current system, where this command is executed

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}'
```

**Current output**

```
fileabc.txt
fileABC.txt
filedata
fisample
```

**Expected output**

```
hostname    fileabc.txt
            fileABC.txt
            filedata
            fisample
```

If we am execute this on multipal server and store the date in one file then for understanding the start & the end line of the particular server we are trying to do this.

if there is any better solution, please advice.

Comment: You have to clarify what it is you want to do.

Comment: The 9th column of the `ls -l` output contains the filenames. Why not just use `printf '%s\n' *` instead of `ls -l`? Do you want to tag each line of this with the hostname, or do you just want to "store the date in a file" (`date >file`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the exact output of the updated question:

```
ls -1 | awk -vhostname="$(hostname)" \
            'NR == 1 { printf("%-20s\t%s\n", hostname, $0) }
             NR > 1  { printf("%-20s\t%s\n", "", $0) }'
```

This allocates a 20 character wide column for the hostname, and adds the output of `ls -1` in a second column.  The columns are tab-separated and the hostname only occurs in the first line.

---

It seems as if you're asking about how to get the hostname of the current system and how to use that in either a filename or inside a file, to be able to tell what system the data came from.

The hostname of a machine is given by the `hostname` command.  This usually gives the full hostname, including domain name (if defined), while `hostname -s` gives the name up to the first dot:

```
$ hostname
client.local

$ hostname -s
client
```

If you have some command, and you'd like to create a filename for where to store its output, then you may do this:

```
somecommand >"$(hostname)_output.txt"
```

This will run `somecommand` (for example, your `ls` command) and store its output in a file with a name that contains the hostname of the system it ran on.

If you'd like to insert the hostname in a header or footer in the file:

```
( echo "HEADER: The following comes from $(hostname)"
  somecommand
  echo "FOOTER: The above came from $(hostname)" ) >outputfile
```

or, with `awk`:

```
somecommand | awk -v hostname="$(hostname)" 'BEGIN { print "## From:", hostname }
                  { print } END { print "## From:", hostname }'
```

where `somecommand` is the command you want to store the output of.

If you want to tag every line with the hostname:

```
somecommand | awk -v hostname="$(hostname)" '{ print hostname, $0 }'
```

or, variations thereof.

The `-v` option to `awk` lets you set an `awk` variable on the command line.

It may be that you have a `HOSTNAME` environment variable defined as well.  In this case, you may use that without using the `hostname` command:

```
awk -v hostname="$HOSTNAME" ...
```

or, you may access the environment variable directly inside the `awk` code with `ENVIRON["HOSTNAME"]`.

Comment: the very first one worked for my code. you explained with many example.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the content of the "HOSTNAME" environment variable like this:

```
ls -l | awk '{print ENVIRON["HOSTNAME"] ": " $9}'
```

If this does not work, see if the variable "HOST" contains what you need:

```
ls -l | awk '{print ENVIRON["HOST"] ": " $9}'
```

If neither are set, try this:

```
ls -l | awk 'BEGIN { h="/bin/hostname"; h | getline host; close (h);} {print host ": " $9}'
```

This calls the `/bin/hostname` command once and puts its output into the `host` variable, which is then prefixed before each line.

EDIT: You have changed the question, stating that the hostname should only be printed once.  Here is the variant:

```
ls -1 | awk 'BEGIN { h="/bin/hostname"; h | getline  host; close (hostname);} { if (NR < 2) {print host}; print "\t" $1}'
```

Comment: `$HOSTNAME` is not generally set on every Unix system (mine for example). You would have to get the hostname in another way, or describe how to set it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks. Is HOST set on your system, then?

Comment: No, but you easily just add another line before the `ls` that sets and exports any variable that you want to use.

Comment: OK, I have inserted a shell command into `awk`, seemed more clean.

Comment: I am unable to get the require output.

Comment: @user3561766 You have changed the question, and now I have changed the script.

Comment: I am just unable to put this into my code.

Comment: I am unable to create a chat windows, could you create a window.

Comment: The question does not state that you wish to create a chat window. You asked for the command, and what I did works!  If you wish to ask something more, please do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65748/discussion-between-user3561766-and-ned64).